# Preferred Windows Java Development Environment

Tags: java, windows, preferences

I've been a Linux Java developer for years and have loved it. I just got a new laptop which is running Windows 7. I could wipe the drive and go back to my typical Linux dev setup: vim for editing, tabbed Bash windows running javac and java for smaller projects, ant for big projects

That said, I'm really thinking it couldn't hurt to learn to develop in a new environment. So, with that in mind, are there any Windows-based Java devs out there? What setup do you like to use to get things done? It'd be interesting to hear both ways to emulate my Linux-based environment as well as completely different styles that I might benefit from trying.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you haven't used and IDE like eclipse?

Comment: No reason as such, just never learned to work with one! I tried using eclipse a little at work on linux but my workstation didn't have the RAM to load all the file structure into the project without crawling along.

Comment: Just curious, I had a former manager who was a diehard Emacs user and scoffed at using IDEs.  Your feelings on the matter would help provide more useful answers.  And you're absolutely right, Eclipse will take every bit of RAM you give it.

Answer (score 10):

I use [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org/) for all my Java development work, also on a laptop. (I recommend not wiping the drive of a laptop, as special software for laptop-specific features, e.g. webcam and Bios configuration, might not run on Linux: use virtualization for Linux)

Besides NetBeans I have Notepad++ for all "quick & dirty" programming, though start-up times for NetBeans 6.8 are so good and memory consumption is quite low, I often have NetBeans open all the time. NetBeans has ANT, and it has an intergrated console (with input!) for your smaller projects. No need to run in a seperate window.

It takes some time to configure everything right in Netbeans & Notepad++ (think of templates, code-completion timing, indentation, colouring, paths, etc.) but once you've got it, it works like a charm.

---

I tried Eclipse, but it's really a matter of taste; I never have liked SWT applications.

Answer (score 6):

When I was doing Java development on Windows I used Eclipse as the IDE.  It would be quite a different setup from what you're used to, and [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) does require a bit of tweaking before it behaves out but overall it was a fairly pleasant experience.

If you rely on outside packages for your development you might want to look into [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/).  When I used it it was a really nice way to manage dependencies and be able to pull down the latest version of each package I relied, build it from source, and make sure my code still played nice with the latest release of said packages.

---

If you are partial to VIM as an interface you might also be interested in this question: [Vim Commands in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28793/vim-commands-in-eclipse).

Answer (score 3):

I have always been a Java Windows developer, so I have never crossed into the Linux development side. My Windows Java IDE of choice has always been [Eclipse for Java Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/).

I strongly encourage you to try developing in Java on Windows. Come to find out if you don't like it or nostalgia kicks in, (*whichever comes first*) I recommend downloading [Sun's Virtual Box](http://www.virtualbox.org/), install Linux along with your preferred tools for developing and you can now start where you had left off while still using Windows as your operating system.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What do you develop in? Do you use an IDE? If not, is there some sort of better command line than the cmd that comes with the system? Even just installing a nice editor and having a nice command line tool would be nice.

Comment: I had updated my answer, I've used a few: NetBeans, BlueJ and Eclipse. Eclipse took the cake for me.

Comment: @JF: There's Cygwin (http://www.cygwin.com/) which will give you a linux like command line API in windows.  There's also PowerShell console (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177003.aspx) but that sort of requires learning PowerShell (language).

Answer (score 3):

Well, there's always your friend the IDE! Both [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) and [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/) are free to try out and work well on Windows, Linux, and Mac.

While there's something to be said for the dedicated editors of the world like Vi and Emacs, I sometimes find the jack-of-all-trades IDE that is dedicated to doing everything for your programming needs and doing them all adequately to be pretty handy.

Answer (score 3):

If I had a choice I would probably use Eclipse. It is a good looking, easy to use and flexible IDE tailored mostly for Java, although with plugins (of which there are heaps!) it can do anything (or near enough :)

However at work we must use IntelliJ which is commercial. Great product with heaps of features and because it is designed for Java development it really supports it in as many ways as possible.

Both IDEs can be used with ANT or if you want something different, and I have heard more powerful, you could check out Maven.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of emulating a linux environment, have a look at Cygwin.

In terms of what to use in Windows, an IDE is really a must. There are three worth looking at out of the box: Eclipse, NetBeans and IDEA. All are open source, but IDEA's open source version is kind of crippled. Beyond basic JavaSE development you need the paid for version, but then again it is as good as vim and bash in almost anything. Eclipse is "standard." And NetBeans is the closest to the bleading edge.

All of those IDEs run on Linux as well, so if you haven't used one until now, I imagine you will gravitate towards Cygwin, at which point you might as well wipe and install your favorite Linux distro.

Answer (score 2):

definitely use an IDE. I recommend 
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/free_java_ide.html

Answer (score 1):

Java development ... with vim? (shudder)

You many wonderful IDEs out there. [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) among them - and it runs in Windows/Linux.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to be an adventurer to use an IDE, download cygwin and setup a 'linux-like' development enivornment, that's what i do for my own projects when the final server is on a Linux env and i want to keep the same build scripts and environment, even u can use rsync to keep them in sync if u want to have a backup linux env. for development.

Answer (score 1):

I used Eclipse IDE for all my Java needs throughout my semester long Java course. I also used the vrapper plugin to get the vim keybindings for movement.

I know for a fact that going this route made writing Java code a whole lot easier than had I gone my normal route of vim+command line. I'm also fairly sure that is the environment my brother uses programming for Amazon.

For writing Java code on windows OR linux (I mostly exclusively use linux), Eclipse is the best. Having also used NetBeans, I can tell you my preference was for Eclipse - it felt more solid, more "real". I'm not sure how else to describe it. Of course I never worked on a huge (> 2000 LOC) -- ((< 2000 LOC) if you read LISP) -- program, so I don't have any experience with the serious sluggish issues formerly mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Linux will be a bit faster compared to Windows. Personally I would love to stay with Linux but try using IDE like Eclipse/NetBeans which are highly used in project development.

Answer (score 0):

I realise that it's not a recent question but I may have a quite current answer.

As long as the choice is yours stay with Linux or Mac OS eventually. Windows isn't really a familiar environment for java dev. By the way, I'm pretty curious how you had found windows after longer time on linux.

No matter which OS will be the one of your choice, the real deal is an IDE. I'm really amazed by devs using VIM for JVM development. I believe that's possible, I've seen it myself. Although, the features IDE could give you are far beyond that.

1. Eclipse - still probably the most popular considering all devs. Not sure why - probably because it had appeared before others IDE. Beside it's used as a base platform for lot of different specific applications (including IDEs for different languages as well).
2. Netbeans - it's the one with the lowest learning curve, pretty decent and easy to use. I enjoyed it.
3. Intellij IDEA - I haven't spotted for quite a long time any other IDE in use among professional JAVA and JVM related devs. It may be a bit harder to start with than Netbeans but it is really powerful IDE. The drawback is, to have all the power under your fingers you should go for Ultimate edition which is on commercial license. There is still Community version, a bit thinner but still worth of giving a try. By the power I mean support for all the recent stacks, ORMs, build tools GUI libs and frameworks.

Vim and Ant? I know it was 2010 back then, but come on...

Answer (score 0):

You can use IntelliJ IDEA by JetBrains for development on Windows. Its a great IDE and lives true by its name. It has great code completion and makes you a productive Java developer once you get used to it and know all the shortcuts and the productive tips and tricks.

Even though you go back to Linux after a while I would recommend you to use IntelliJ on Linux too. Its a great tool and removes all the unnecessary nuances so that you can focus on the core development part.

Here is the link: [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)

Answer (score 0):

I am using Windows for Java development. 
For JDK installation you could get the zip file, extract to a path like `c:\java` and define `JDK_HOME` system variable. After this, remember to include this variable with bin folder to the path. This declaration should look like `%JAVA_HOME\bin%` (so similar to linux).
I Use IntelliJ IDEA as my IDE. It's very useful, fast and have a large community of developers.
If you have to use terminal PowerShell is great and you can combine to hyper.is or ConEMU/CMDER.
If you need a light code editor could use VSCode with a vim plugin.