# Is there a command in Eclipse like Vim's "o"?

Tags: eclipse, vim

I find it useful to be able to create an empty new line after current line. `End Enter` does exactly what I want, but it is not easy to type. Something closer to default keyboard row, like Ctrl+o, would be much better. Can I do this using default Eclipse commands, or is there any plugin providing such functionality?

Comment: This question is related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/28793/130224

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Shift-Enter` inserts a line below the cursor and `Ctrl-Shift-Enter` inserts above.